# Thread Safety of Factory Class

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a factory class let say `ApppleFactory` that creates a new instance of `Apple` by invoking `getApple()` method. There is only one shared instance of `ApppleFactory`.

```
class ApppleFactory {
    private static Apple apple = null;

    private ApppleFactory() {
    }

    public static Apple getApple() {
        apple = new Apple();
        //do some other work on this apple instance
        return apple; //finally return it
    }
}
```

Now if multiple threads access this `getApple()` and work with this mutable data  `apple` then there could be a chance of unsafety. How to overcome this problem?

Comment: Synchronize the method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clearly the `static` field is the problem. Just get rid of it.

```
class ApppleFactory {
    public Apple getApple() {
        Apple apple = new Apple();
        //do some other work on this apple instance
        return apple; //finally return it
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The  `apple` field is not required as you create at each time a new instance in `getApple()` .
So you can remove it :

```
class ApppleFactory {

    private ApppleFactory() {
    }


    public static Apple getApple() {
        Apple  apple = new Apple();
        //do some other work on this apple instance
        return apple; //finally return it
    }
}
```

Now if your need changes and you want to reuse this field somewhere else in your factory class, the class would be so mutable and you should so use explicit synchronization to create and retrieve `Apple` instances.
For example with your actual implementation relying on static modifiers:

```
class ApppleFactory {

    private static Apple apple;

    private ApppleFactory() {
    }

    public static synchronized Apple getApple() {
        apple = new Apple();
        //do some other work on this apple instance
        return apple; //finally return it
    }

    public static synchronized void consumeApple() {
        apple.eatByMe();
    }

}
```

Note that providing only `static` methods in a factory couples strongly the clients of the class to the class.  As alternative you could change clients methods into instance methods by using the classical singleton, the enum singleton pattern or a dependency injection container.